# QTextEdit выводит пустую строку

Tags: python, pyqt5

Пример кода:

```
class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Парсер hh.ru")
        self.ui.sites.setWordWrapMode(QtGui.QTextOption.NoWrap)
        self.ui.start.clicked.connect(self.Start)
        self.ui.stop.clicked.connect(self.Stop)
        self.sites = self.ui.sites.toPlainText()

    def Start(self):
        check_start_or_stop = 0
        print(self.sites)

    def Stop(self):
        check_start_or_stop = 1



if __name__ =="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MyWin()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Макет:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(633, 621)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(633, 621))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(633, 621))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 451, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.sites = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.sites.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 611, 231))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.sites.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.sites.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.sites.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.sites.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.sites.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContentsOnFirstShow)
        self.sites.setObjectName("sites")
        self.start = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.start.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 270, 311, 71))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.start.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.start.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.start.setFont(font)
        self.start.setObjectName("start")
        self.stop = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.stop.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 270, 311, 71))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.stop.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.stop.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.stop.setFont(font)
        self.stop.setObjectName("stop")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 360, 611, 251))
        self.textEdit.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.textEdit.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(11, 342, 47, 13))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ссылки на список резюме на сайте hh.ru (скопируйте из адресной строки браузера)"))
        self.start.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "СТАРТ"))
        self.stop.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "СТОП"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Логи"))
```

Пытаясь вывести `self.sites` при нажатии на кнопку Старт. У меня выводит пустую строку, хотя QtextEdit(sites) заполнен.

Comment: Потому что вы выводите пустую строку ) Попробуйте print(self.ui.sites.toPlainText())

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Стоп, а как мне тогда перезаписать в переменную это всё?

Comment: В методе Start перед принтом присваивать self.sites = self.ui.sites.toPaintText() Тогда можно и print(self.sites). Не путайте вашу строку self.sites и виджет self.ui.sites в данном классе

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Спасибо. Давно с pyqt не работал, подзабыл